# url to new format

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Given below is my .htaccess file. It is not working on localhost apache (www is root directory on C:/apache/www) "url" is directory and I want output like this

http://localhost/url/index.php?username=shah
to
http://localhost/url/shah

I change windows host file 127.0.0.1 localhost
& also enable mod_rewrite in httpd.conf file & AllowOverride none to AllowOverride All
& root Directory to C:/apache/www

```
//==============================HTaccess==================================//
 Options:
# -MultiViews: Turns off multiviews so it doesn't interfer with our rewrite rules
# -Indexes: Stop directory listings
# +FollowSymlinks: Let out rewrite rules work

Options -MultiViews -Indexes +FollowSymlinks

<IfModule mod_security.c>
    # Turn off mod_security filtering.
    # SecFilterEngine Off

    # The below probably isn't needed, but better safe than sorry.
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /url/404.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value register_globals 0
    php_value magic_quotes_gpc 0
    php_value session.auto_start 0
    php_value safe_mode 0
</IfModule>

<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
    php_value register_globals 0
    php_value magic_quotes_gpc 0
    php_value session.auto_start 0
    php_value safe_mode 0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /url/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?username=$1

#RewriteRule ^view-content/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ content.php?pageid=$1&title=$2 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript text/css text/html text/xml
</IfModule>
//==============================HTaccess==================================//
```

Please tell me what to do?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly isn't working?  Is it just the RewriteRule or is the whole .htaccess file being ignored?

Comment: Please read below answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /url/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} username\=(.*)
RewriteRule index\.php$ /url/%1
```

Hope this helps you... :)

Comment: above example redirect to page not found

Comment: Can you tell me which url it redirects?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to redirect a request of `/url/index.php?username=shah` externally to `/url/shah`, try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*?)username=([^&]+)&*(.*)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /url/%3?%1%4 [L,R=301]
```

Otherwise, for the reverse direction:

```
RewriteCond $0 !=index.php
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ index.php?username=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, Your code is working but with page not found its changing url locally & displaying page not found.Online phpprojects.netau.net/url/index.php?username=hereusername nothing displaying only querystring

Comment: My code for is working index.php?username=shah & now I want to know about this issue RewriteRule ^view-content/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ content.php?pageid=$1&title=$2 [L] why this does not work